# Magento pixel without tax

Tags: magento-1.7, php

We have a pixel at our success.phtml and at this moment we get the grand total by grand_total. By the grand total the order amount is shown including tax and shipping costs. We want to change this to the amount without tax and shipping.

Does someone know how to change this?

```
<?php
  $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
  $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
  $order->load($lastOrderId); 
  $total = $order->getData('grand_total');
?>

<img src="http://www.domain.nl/tuin/img.php?campaignID=a1fddd&productID=8e7ba6&conversionType=sale&transactionID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId()?>&transactionAmount=<?= $total ?>&currency=EUR" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the the price without taxes and without shipping cost like this

```
$total = $order->getSubtotalInclTax() - $order->getTaxAmount();
```

Comment: Hi Marius, I also saw the other comment below can I also just use the subtotal or has it to be yours with the subtotalincluding and then minus taxamount?

Comment: If it works, sure. I just offers an alternative

Answer (score 1):

That should be `$order->getData('subtotal')`. You can do the following: `var_dump($order->getData());` to see all the values you have available.

Comment: Hi Mayers, do you mean that i should just change  $total = $order->getData('grand_total'); to  $total = $order->getData('subtotal');?

Comment: Yes that's correct